# Make NodeJs and/or V8 output CRLF at the end of console.log instead LF

Tags: node.js, v8

In NodeJs for Windows `v14.16.1` a call to `console.log` outputs a line with LF as a line ending, while in other versions of Node for Windows the line ending is CRLF.

we redirect the console output to a file:

```
node my-script.js > my-file.txt
```

which is then stored in GIT

This gets very annoying with GIT as different people commit the same file with different line endings due to different versions of NodeJs for Windows working differently.

In our repo `git config autocrlf` is set to `false` (which means to commit as-is without any transformations)

Is there a way to configure NodeJS or V8 to use the specific (in our case CRLF) line ending for the console output?

Comment: Can you not configure your source control to normalize line endings automatically?  Or, use some custom pre-check-in action to normalize it automatically for you?  Or change `node my-script.js > my-file.txt` to pipe it through a normalizer.

Comment: autocrlf set to false instructs not to normalize endings and commit as is, that's the way we prefer, i know it 100% certain, because the file checks out with CRLF and my setting is `git config --local autocrlf` says `false`

Comment: custom action looks like an overkill, i hope line endings of console can be configured in nodejs/v8

Comment: Since it sounds like an issue you have in developer PC's, can't you just simply upgrade your local installation of NodeJS?  Why are you stuck in `v14.16.1`?

Comment: I looked and did not find any configuration for `console.log()` line endings in nodejs.  It appears to be coded a certain way by platform.  There are plenty of examples of people overriding `console.log()` and replacing it entirely in order to do their own thing, but  then you're on the hook for reimplementing most/all of its functionality (depending upon what you need it to do).

Comment: it's not the issue with my PC or any other team-member PC it's the problem with new people coming and old people leaving, it's a way greater issue to make sure everyone has the same version of NodeJs on their desktops, laptops, other laptops and their mom's computer

the version of Node is not critical since the script is only to be run at the compile time (a homemade tool), and it's convenient not to have to worry about the exact version of Node, having a specific version of node installed on a laptop - is a luxury, for one certain project you work on, what if you have more?

Comment: @jfriend00 overriding `console.log` is an option, another option is to use `process.stdout.write`

Comment: Using `process.stdout.write()` is usually part of overriding `console.log()`.  The bigger issue is that you have to implement how `console.log()` turns everything into a string as that isn't automatic for some data types.  Even just for `console.log(obj)`.

Comment: @jfriend00 i guess this is what i will have to do, thankfully (in our case (as of now)) it's all about text being sent to the output, but like you can see it's a hack nonetheless

Comment: First question I have is why are people running bare scripts instead of having some kind of launcher for them that can correctly encode the output? [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com) is a common favorite for this in the Node world, but there are others, including stuff as simple as [`npm run`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-run-script) with configured scripts, including any rewriting already baked in.

Comment: @tadman we had gulp in our build scripts but then we had to throw it away because of its limitations, so for us bare scripts as homemade tools proved to work better, anyway new shiny tools pop up every day, it's not our priority to adapt them as they pop, we prefer to keep the proven tools to keep working

Comment: Fair enough, though surely `npm run` isn't that *exotic*. What about giving the script an `--output FILE` option that does the encoding correctly?

Comment: @tadman wrapping a script to `npm run` isn't a problem, if it solves the problem i will use it, i didn't know npm run normalizes the line endings, if it does thanks for the info

Comment: It doesn't normalize the endings, but you can tack on whatever CRLF sorcery you need in the specific command it executes.

Comment: @tadman ok, then it lands in post/pre-processing which can be done in many ways, i can chain a bare script that opens the file and rewrites it, or i can use a git hook, or i can override the console.log or set `git config autocrlf`, or any other way, it's all fair solutions, but my questions is about whether or not i can avoid it

Comment: Not really, short of this plan: Acquire Microsoft. Make WIndows 12 use LF line endings. Upgrade your team to Windows 12. Problem solved!

Comment: @tadman yes! that's the plan :P